# i18next-http-middleware - Does the removeLngFromUrl has been removed?

Tags: node.js, url-rewriting, i18next

I'm new to i18next and I'm trying to remove the lng parameter from the URL once it has been save as new language.
I saw in the documentation of i18next-express-middleware that there was an option named "removeLngFromUrl" but I cannot find it anymore on i18next-http-middleware.

Am I getting this wrong ? Is there a new way to remove it ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of v1.0.7 it is still there, just not in their documentation.
[image: From their codebase]